# How to apply hann window to unsigned integer ADC

Tags: analog-to-digital, c, fixed-point, embedded-systems

I am using Arm-Cortex M3 Microcontroller and CMSIS for FFT, my microcontroller does not support floating point unit therefore I have to use fixed point (Q15 or Q31) for calculation.
Before calculate FFT, I need to apply hanning window on to my data collected from ADC 12-bit (0-4095). My ADC data ranges from 1800 ~ 3200.
Here is a sample code I have tried so far. Did I correctly apply?

```
double hann[512];
uint32_t ADC[512]; /* data range 1800 ~ 3200 */
q31_t input[512]; /* fixed point */

// Hann window
for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
{
    hann[i] = 0.5 * (1 - cos(2*PI*i/511));
}

// apply hann window to ADC data
for (int j = 0; j < 512; j++)
{
    ADC[j] = (ADC[j] - DC) * hann[j];
    input[j] = (q31_t)ADC[j] << 19; // convert to fixed point Q31 from 12-bit
}
```

Comment: I am not sure it is the right forum. Anyway, you can not multiply different types, which u did. Also, I would avoid the allocation of the Hann window into a memory, which takes a lot of time, and unify both of the loops (which also takes a lot of time)

Comment: @Gideon Genadi Kogan I don't know if this is the right forum either but thanks for the input. _avoid the allocation of the Hann window into a memory_ ya you are right, I will follow @Marcus Müller advices - calculate and convert to fixed point format on another language then save it as a constant `const int` to store in ROM memory. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Did I correctly apply?

No. At least not according to your plan:

```
ADC[j] = (ADC[j] - DC) * hann[j];
```

here you're multiplying an integer `ADC[j]-DC` with a `double`; that's a floating point operation. If your processor has no floating point hardware, that means your compiler has to simulate that multiplication in software. Also, saving back to the ADC readout region doesn't sound like a good idea. (It doesn't "save memory", your computation is done in registers anyway, and you're actually telling the compiler that you want the memory `ADC` points to to have a specific value, which it might take as a hint to actually store that throwaway value.)

Then you convert that back to an unsigned integer to save it in `ADC[j]`? Your compiler should tell you that's a bad idea. If anything, scale in floating point while you still can before truncating to integer values.

So, you need to first create your Hann window in a fixed-point version. There's little reason to do that on the microcontroller itself; `cos` is an expensive function both in terms of CPU time and program memory, so on a Cortex-M, you typically avoid it.

Instead, you'd probably take your favourite language on a PC, and calculate a Hann window, scale it up to fit your desired signed range, round it and save it as the Q-format of your choice. You'd take the first half of that (it being symmetrical means you don't really need both halves) and integrate as constant into your program.

At run-time, you'd multiply with these correctly pre-scaled integer numbers, so that you don't have to shift separately – saving an unnecessary separate operation. (Remember: `<<1` is the same as `*2` for integers.)

> My ADC data ranges from 1800 ~ 3200.

So, you really have only a dynamic range of 400, i.e. less than 9 bits. In that case, you would gain very little from using a number format with 32 binary digits. Q1.15 is more than plenty.

By the way, subtracting the DC component prior to doing an FFT makes little sense. Just ignore the 0. bin of the FFT after transformation – that's the DC component.

Second "by the way": The `q31_t` type [is](https://arm-software.github.io/CMSIS_5/DSP/html/arm__math__types_8h.html#adc89a3547f5324b7b3b95adec3806bc0) just an alias for `int32_t`. It might be good to not treat it as if it was anything special. Not specifically fond of that type, "Q1.31" is an *interpretation* of data in an integer, not actually it's type (just as "banana count" is an interpretation of an integer, not a special integer count).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the input. I have a question about this "_multiply with these correctly pre-scaled integer numbers_" if multiplying both fixed-point 15(Q15/int16_t) will cause overflow? e.g `int16_t save = (int16_t) fixed_point_hann * (int16_t)fixed_point_adc`. Or do I need to convert hann and adc to fixed-point 8(Q8/int8_t) and multiply these two and save it in a (Q15/int16_t) variable e.g. `int16_t save = (int8_t) fixed_point_hann * (int8_t)fixed_point_adc`

Comment: "Do I convert Hann to fixed point" yes: that's what I explicitly wrote.